# create another column based on the values on a column in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data frame called p, it content is as below:

```
structure(list(AGENT = c(45693, 45693, 45693, 45693, 45693, 45693, 
45693, 45693, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627, 42627)), .Names = "AGENT", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to add two more columns to this data frame called p. For example, if the p$AGENT==45693, I like to set the Location to dallas, and the provider to ATT.

I haved tried something like this:

```
library(data.table)
p<-p[,LOCATION:=if(AGENT==45693, c("Dallas"))]
```

I get this error:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "p<-p[,LOCATION:=if(AGENT==45693,"
```

is data.table the best method to accomplish this? Any ideas?

Comment: It's an error in your `if` statement. I think you might prefer to use `ifelse`.

Comment: It's better to make a `data.table` with your mappings `locs <- data.table(AGENT=c("45693","42627"),LOCATION=c("DALLAS","HOUSTON"))` and then merge that information back. Also, probably store AGENT as a character or factor, not a floating-point number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to make p a data.table before you can use data.table syntax on it.

```
p<-data.table(p)
#create(update) column called LOCATION and set it to Dallas if AGENT==45693
p[AGENT==45693,LOCATION:="Dallas"]
```

the first argument in the brackets is the filter and the second is called the J where you can either select columns or in this case assign a column.

Answer (score 1):

The anser of @Dean is very good. Mine just to mention the fact that you can also use `:=` assignment operator to create a vector of names. Here 2 versions:

```
library(data.table)
p <- data.table(dat)
p[AGENT==45693,c('LOCATION','Provider') := list("Dallas",'ATT')]

DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[AGENT==45693, `:=`(LOCATION ="Dallas", Provider = "ATT")]
```